# Programmatically get port 80 Web Application Default URL for Farm?

Tags: object-model, web-application, alternate-access-mapping, web-application-zones

How would I programmatically get the port 80 Web Application Default URL for the Farm?

Comment: In the concept of SharePoint there is no default web application on port 80. In most of my installations there are multiple web aplications using port 80 and non of them is using the server name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var webService = SPFarm.Local.Services.OfType<SPWebService>().FirstOrDefault();
if (webService != null)
{
    var webApp = webService.WebApplications.FirstOrDefault(wa => wa.GetResponseUri(SPUrlZone.Default).Port == 80);
    if (webApp != null)
    {
        Uri webAppUri = new Uri(webApp.GetResponseUri(SPUrlZone.Default).AbsoluteUri);
```